# Android 11: How to access app specific files from Browser

Tags: android, local-storage, scoped-storage

My app is creating some html files (reports) that user can open by using web browser.

But from Android 11 data storage privacy, the browser cannot read the html files from app private storage.

Storage Access Framework requires manual intervention.

Is there any workaround, so that web browser can access the generated html files from my app specific storage?

Comment: ACTION_VIEW with FileProvider to serve your file will do.

Comment: Tried that, but it is working only for public directories, not with the app specific private directory (for Android 11).
While the html reports are generating only inside app packege.

Comment: Below is the code:
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, FileProvider.getUriForFile(mActivity, mActivity.getPackageName()+".provider",file));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: What specifically happens with that `Intent`? I can see where the user may not have a Web browser that supports the `content` scheme.

Comment: The intent is for Browser, that will open the file uri. While the restriction of Android 11 for external storage, file uri is returning null value which is causing the crash.

Comment: That makes no sense. Of course you can use FileProvider too for app specific directorories. Please put complete code in your post as we cannot see where the used file comes from.

Comment: I cannot put the complete code because of confidentiality. But I am trying to understand, how the external apps (web browser, gmail etc), can access the files in your app specific storage (com.example.abc)?
FYI: My app is creating files on app specific storage programatically, which earlier I was showing to user from chrome browser or sharing it via gmail. Now because of storage scope, it is not allowing. Have you worked on similar issue before?

Comment: Finally I figured out the way to do this, by using Storage Access Framework

Comment: You can put those less than ten lines of code here without them containing any confidential stuff. As there is nothing configential on serving a html file with a file provider and ACTION_VIEW. And yes i did share files from all locatiins that FileProvidet can handle before. You dont need saf for thosr locations.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to access this now by using Storage Access Framework (scoped storage), instead of using app private storage.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

Use Intent: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to get the scoped storage permission. Then write the file into the storage:

```
try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
            fileOutputStream.write(("Overwritten at " + System.currentTimeMillis() +
                    "\n").getBytes());
            // Let the document provider know you're done by closing the stream.
            fileOutputStream.close();
            pfd.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

These files can be accessed using browser intent.

Comment: You mean ACTIIN_VIEW? But pictures in `<img> tags will not be loaded. Or do they?